# ¿Por que me sale este error con reverze_lazy?

Tags: python, django

tengo el siguiente codigode mi funcion para crear un formulario

```
 def correspondencia_view(request):

 if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CorrespondenciaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
         # si es todo correcto el archivo es guardado
                 form.save()
                 #este es el retorno de la vista url que esta en el archivo urls.py        
                 return redirect('correspondencia:corresp_listar')           
                 # caso contrario se vuelve otra vez a generar el formulario
else:
     form = CorrespondenciaForm() 
return render(request, 'registrarCorrespondencia/index.html', {'form': form})
```

y mi clase

```
  class CorrespCrear(CreateView):

   model = corresp
   form_class = CorrespondenciaForm
   template_name = 'registrarCorrespondencia/index.html'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('correspondencia:corresp_listar')
```

y mi urls.py esta asi

```
 url(r'^nuevo/$', CorrespCrear.as_view(), name='registrar_corresp'),
```

PERO me sale un error que es el siguiente:

NoReverseMatch at /correspondencia/nuevo/

Reverse for 'corresp_listar' not found. 'corresp_listar' is not a valid view 
function or pattern name.

Este error me sale cuando pongo en guardar en mi formulario, pero en ves de rediccionarme a la pagina donde esta mi tabla de datos, me sale eso, debido a que podria ser?

Comment: Lo que te dice es que en esta linea `success_url = reverse_lazy('correspondencia:corresp_listar')` le dices tu vista, cuando termine el formulario, si todo sale bien, entonces lleva al usuario a esta url, la pregunta es. En tus urls tienes alguna url con el nombre `corresp_listar`?

Comment: al parecer no la tengo, estoy haciendo pruebas con ello ahora mismo, pero si me sirvio de mucha ayuda tu respuesta, gracias , mil gracias , cualquier cambio que ocurra estare poniendolo aqui

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el problema en si estuvo en la Url y el reverse_lazy

solo cambie lo que era corresp_listar hacia lo que es mi lista que tengo creada, gracias a  (German Alzate) que si tenia razon con su comentario que puso en ahi.

mi url quedaria haci
    url(r'^nuevo/$', CorrespCrear.as_view(), name='nuevo'),

```
url(r'^listar/$', CorrespList.as_view(), name='corresp_list'),
```

en donde mi reverse_lazy lo cambie asi

```
 class CorrespCrear(CreateView):
 model = corresp
 form_class = CorrespondenciaForm
 template_name = 'registrarCorrespondencia/index.html'
 success_url = reverse_lazy('correspondencia:corresp_list')
```

y en mi funcion  def correspondencia_view

```
 return redirect('correspondencia:corresp_list')
```

y listo todo me sale muy bien :)